# Node.js error: Cannot find module require

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was practicing some of my node skills with a video I was watching on youtube. I came across an error when I went to run it. it says its a throw error inside module.js:471 but I cant seem to understand why and how to fix it.

[image: Code Screenshot]

my code is in that image since i couldn't get the code tool to work properly

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Narrow this down to the smallest bit of code that can reproduce your problem.  (Should be 1 line in this case.)  Then, paste the actual code.  The code paste tool works just fine... not sure what trouble you're running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line...

```
var express = require('require'),
```

You probably wanted...

```
var express = require('express'),
```

If you're using a recent version of Node.js, consider using `const` in this case as well.

Comment: I have no comment as to how stupid of a mistake that was, thank you for your help.